# Where Is the Lugang Glass Temple?

Tags: taiwan, temples

Accidentally landed on an image of the Lugang Glass Temple which looks absolutely stunning on [Google Images](https://www.google.com.ec/search?q=lugang%20glass%20temple&safe=off&espv=2&biw=1965&bih=1961&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiRiLuq2OLQAhVI2yYKHbZPCfkQ_AUIBigB#imgrc=_).

Unfortunately, searching for the same term on Google Maps says: *We could not find lugang glass temple*. Found one blogger that says its 20 minutes away from Lugang and another one with a similarly vague statement.

**Where is the Lugang Glass Temple exactly?** Does it still exist? Is it a  structure that can be visited?

Comment: According to [this site](https://www.englishintaiwan.com/travel-in-taiwan/central-taiwan-travel/lugang-glass-temple-mazu) it's a replica of a real temple and can be found in a glass factory....

Comment: @pnuts - "this site" is not linked to anywhere.

Comment: @pnuts - Nice, even from here (Ecuador, which redirects me to google.com.ec) now. *This* question is second and "this site" you mentioned is now first. Google's algorithms are at work!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using your image search, I clicked some of the images to be taken to the pages they came from. One, [a blog entry on English in Taiwan](https://www.englishintaiwan.com/travel-in-taiwan/central-taiwan-travel/lugang-glass-temple-mazu), was very useful. It includes this map at the bottom of the page:

[image: map to glass temple]

It also mentions that this is a glass copy of a famous temple, that it's on the grounds of a glass factory, and how to visit. Seems like it has all you need.

Answer (score 5):

Per [this site](https://www.englishintaiwan.com/travel-in-taiwan/central-taiwan-travel/lugang-glass-temple-mazu), it's at Chang Hua County, Lu Gang Township, Lu Gong South 4th Road #30, [here](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Taiwan+Glass+Pavilion/@24.0682308,120.3945603,17.88z/data=!4m13!1m7!3m6!1s0x3469459c7943ae0b:0xe711af7f1fbb2980!2sNo.+30,+Lugong+South+4th+Rd,+Lukang+Township,+Changhua+County,+Taiwan+505!3b1!8m2!3d24.0685762!4d120.3951268!3m4!1s0x0:0x6b9cead7b0b10332!8m2!3d24.0684556!4d120.3948469).

[Booking a tour appears to be available](http://www.timingjump.com.tw/Guide/Booking.aspx)